# Error: more than one library with package name

Tags: android, android-studio

The Android-studio post a Error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugResources'.
>   Error: more than one library with package name 'com.tencent.weibo.sdk.android.component'
>     You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>     However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

Below is my content of build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.insthub.ecmobile"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 17

    testApplicationId "com.insthub.ecmobile.test"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile project(':androidSDK')
compile project(':alipay_lib')
compile project(':eventBus')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile files('libs/Msc.jar')
compile files('libs/UPPayAssistEx.jar')
compile files('libs/UPPayPluginExPro.jar')
compile files('libs/alipay.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/libammsdk.jar')
compile files('libs/pushservice-3.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/umeng_sdk.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.6-with-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/weibosdkcore.jar')
compile project(':androidSDKComponent')
}
```

I can't find "com.tencent.weibo.sdk.android.component"

Comment: who can give me a idea to solve the error

Comment: Don't add jars if you are compiling the same project in. You might run into the same problem with alipay which seems to have been added twice. The package name in the error might be in weibosdkcore.jar and also some of the projects you are compiling in, like :androidSDKComponent or something. It could also be possible that some other lib already uses the weibo lib, check the documentations.

Comment: it is work when i delete  the androidSDKComponent project

Comment: I don't know why reference androidSDKComponnet project it can't work

Comment: androidSDKComponent probably is the name of the weibo lib module. It might not be intended to be used as a module instead of the jar, so they didn't bother renaming it.